# How to read and update Excel from WPF screen

Tags: .net, wpf

PLease provide somoe appropriate link or code to read and update Excel from WPF screen

Comment: haven't tried anything need to start from scrach , new fro WPF..please help me the way to start

Comment: Try using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Should be a good point to start.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I find these link useful. Try out once

> http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/read-write-and-update-an-excel-file-in-wpf/
>
> http://www.dotnetcodesg.com/Article/UploadFile/2/4331/WPF%20Read%20Write%20and%20Update%20in%20an%20EXCEL%20File.aspx